# ls *.csv --ignore="*pattern*" returns files which contain "pattern"

Tags: files, filesystems, directory, ls, search

Why does `ls --ignore` not ignoring the pattern?

Looking at the below example:

```
mkdir books
cd books
touch books_abby.csv
touch books_karen.csv
touch books_david.csv
touch books_tom.csv
```

This creates four files:

```
$ ls
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv  books_tom.csv
```

If however you want to ignore all filename containing "tom" and list them, `books_tom.csv` is still returned:

```
$ ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv  books_tom.csv
```

The expected outcome is for files containing "tom" to be omitted:

```
$ ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"
books_abby.csv  books_david.csv  books_karen.csv
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The flag is described in the `ls` man page like so  *(emphasis is mine)* ...

> do not list *implied* entries matching shell PATTERN

The man page doesn't have much to say about "implied" so what the heck does it mean? An implied entry (file, directory, etc.) is an entry that `ls` will return without  you having explicitly provided an argument that matches that entry. A match can either be the actual name of the entry (`ls books_tom.csv ...` using your example) or a glob that matches it (`ls *tom.csv`, for instance).

Taking this to its logical limit, if you call `ls` with no arguments everything that is returned is implied! I'm assuming that the most common use of `--ignore` is with such an otherwise unadorned `ls` call because it is the easiest way to do a "list everything but X" operation...at least if you want to avoid using any other commands.

So, let's look at your command. With `ls *.csv --ignore="*tom*"` "books_tom.csv" is explicitly referenced by way of the matching pattern `*.csv`. With `ls --ignore="*tom*"`, per the previous paragraph, everything in the directory is implied thus "books_tom.csv" will not be displayed.

If you have extended globbing available in your shell (with bash you can enable with `shopt -s extglob`) you can achieve what you want by crafting a pattern that will exclude 'tom'. For example `ls books_!(tom).csv` would show `books_abby.csv` but not `books_tom.csv`.

(Of course, you can use other tools like `find`, pipe to `grep -v`, etc...I'm just giving a pure `ls` solution.)

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour without `grep`?

Comment: I've tried the `ls books_!(tom).csv` solution and it works :) My actual use case has dates in the filenames (e.g. `2017_10_29`) and I am trying to get a list of all files without the date using `ls *_!(2017_10_29).csv` and `ls *_!("2017_10_29").csv` however it still returns files from that date, any idea why?

Comment: Yes, because `books_2017_` matches the `*_` and `10_29.csv` matches `!(2017_10_29).csv`. If you use `books_!(2017_10_29).csv` that _would_ work. It's better if you use more explicit patterns because `*` is very flexible.

Comment: @Greg it really sounds like you should be using `find` (e.g. `find . -name '*csv' -not -name '*2017_10_29*'`) or, assuming your file names have no whitespace or other strange characters, just `ls *csv | grep -v 2017_10_29`.

Comment: @terdon Thank you, that approach is actually everything I was looking for